# How can I pass conditional value in custom Hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have custom hook `useFetch` that takes `URL` as input and returns 3 data and I have Component `CompanyListing` to display those data. I want to send two different values as a `URL` in that hook using `if else` statement. If no search is done by user then display data from `if endpoint`, and if user search by keyword, then display from `else endpoint`.
This is code that I wrote `CompanyListing.js`

```
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(1);
  let endpoint = `${CONSTANTS.BASE_URL}/companies?page=${counter}`;
  const searchCompanies = (searchTerm) => {
    if (searchTerm === '') {
      endpoint = `${CONSTANTS.BASE_URL}/companies?page=${counter}`;
      //console.log('DEFAULT ENDPOINT', endpoint);
    } else {
      endpoint = `${CONSTANTS.BASE_URL}/companies?search=${searchTerm}`;
      //console.log('SEARCH ENDPOINT', endpoint);
    }
  };
  //console.log('USEFETCH ENDPOINT', endpoint);
  const [companies, isLoading, meta] = useFetch(endpoint);
  return (
    <>
      <div data-testid="search-box">
        <SearchCompany callback={searchCompanies} />
      </div>
      {!isLoading ? (
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row" data-testid="company-list">
            {companies.length !== 0 && companies
              ? companies.map((company) => <CompanyLists key={company.id} {...company} data-testid="company-list" />)
              : 'No companies'}
          </div>
          <Pagination meta={meta} counter={counter} setCounter={setCounter} data-testid="paginate" />
        </div>
      ) : (
        <Spinner />
      )}
    </>
  );
};
export default CompanyListing;
```

When I tried calling `useFetch` inside `if else`, it goes against the rules of hooks and when I tried doing like in code above, I can't pass search endpoint to `useFetch`. Any idea how can I fix it? I tried by making all fetch on same component and it works perfectly but already having custom hook, I don't want to repeat code again.
And any idea why I am getting 5 console for same thing ?
Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: can you create a working demo of this on codesandbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue I think is that, your parent component is not being re-rendered when `searchCompanies` is called so as result `useFetch` won't get called, and also you can't use that inside the if else also,

So, I think you can do something like this, maintain the endpoint in state and change it when ever `searchCompanies` is being called, in that way your component will be re-rendered and you will get the latest endpoint.

```
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(1);
const [endpoint,setEndPoint] = useState(`${CONSTANTS.BASE_URL}/companies?page=${counter}`);

const searchCompanies = (searchTerm) => {
  if (searchTerm === '') {
    setEndPoint(`${CONSTANTS.BASE_URL}/companies?page=${counter}`);
  } else {
    setEndPoint(`${CONSTANTS.BASE_URL}/companies?search=${searchTerm}`);
  }
};

//console.log('USEFETCH ENDPOINT', endpoint);
const [companies, isLoading, meta] = useFetch(endpoint);
```

Comment: Thank you Vivek. That was really easy trick which I couldn't think of. Really appreciate it. Can you tell me what is going on with those console outputs ?